# Find Location of an IP with Accuracy to the City or Street Level

Tags: ip, geolocation

Is there a solution/code/service to find an IP with accuracy to the City level in the sense of the IP's geolocation?

How would you implement this on your own? Would you need to fetch a live update of the geolocation data in the backend?

I know that mapping an IP to a country is fairly straightforward since it is relatively fixed.
How about cities?

Comment: From a privacy perspective, I sure as hell hope not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, there is, based on finding the network latency between the IP address and a large number of routers with known locations. See [this paper](http://www.usenix.org/event/nsdi11/tech/full_papers/Wang_Yong.pdf). I'm not aware of any commercial implementations, and it would be a lot of work to implement for yourself.

Comment: The paper's a good read, I've been reading it once but lost the link. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @slhck: any opensource or commercial implementation? a lot of websites can show ip with location.

Comment: any opensource or commercial implementation? a lot of websites can show ip with location.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a service: Google Latitude, that even if they are using only a browser, can pinpoint most people fairly accurately. Even though he was not near any hotspots, there was a previous poster, who said they pinned him down to within 100 feet. Here is how they do it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API